# synology php ftp_ssl_connect - Call to undefined function

Tags: php, ssl, synology

First time asking a question here, please be gentle :-)

I'm writing a PHP command-line script on a Synology box to fetch files via ftps, and start out with this bit:

```
$ftp = ftp_ssl_connect("ftp.example.com");
```

When run from the command line, I get

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function ftp_ssl_connect() in ...
```

phpinfo() tells me:

```
...
Registered PHP Streams => php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, https, ftps, zip, compress.zlib, compress.bzip2
Registered Stream Socket Transports => tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv3, sslv2, tls
...
openssl
OpenSSL support => enabled
OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 1.0.1p-fips 9 Jul 2015
OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 1.0.1p-fips 9 Jul 2015
```

and `/etc/php/conf.d/extensions.ini` contains `extension = openssl.so` (without an initial `;`)

It seems to me that all the prerequisites for `ftp_ssl_connect()` are in place.

fwiw:

```
$ uname -a
Linux DiskStation01 2.6.32.12 #5644 Wed Oct 28 12:36:45 CST 2015 armv5tel GNU/Linux synology_88f6282_213
```

What would be the next place to look?

Comment: FTP support => enabled
??

Comment: Yes, that was it, as you can see from my comment below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type `php -m` to see the compiled in modules, as [PHP does not ship the FTP extension by default if not on Windows](http://php.net/manual/en/ftp.installation.php). Calling `phpinfo()` should also show the compiler switches used, and if they include `--enable-ftp`.

The curious thing is I just tried this on an RS812 of mine, and it shows both the FTP and OpenSSL moodules as included, and it works fine:

```
nas-name> php -r "ftp_ssl_connect('test');"
PHP Warning:  ftp_ssl_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: gethostbyname failed
in Command line code on line 1
```

This indicates the `ftp_ssl_connect` is working but not being able to parse the supplied host name. I have no idea why yours would be different unless you compiled PHP yourself.

Comment: That was exactly it: I was looking in the right place, but for the wrong information. FTP is now enabled, and I can log in. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [Niels](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1729885/niels-keurentjes) solution the ftp-Module is missing in the default installation. I needed the module in the CLI version of PHP, but it was unavailable on all four of my Synology Devices (DS 412+, DS 410, RS812+ and RS814+).

Enabling the module in the [Web Station](https://www.synology.com/knowledgebase/DSM/help/WebStation/application_webserv_php) settings did not help, but there is a solution for the CLI version in a [Synology Forum Entry](https://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?t=116033):

> 1. make sure that the ftp extension is selected within php settings of Web Station.
> 2. then edit /etc/php/php.ini to include a line like this:- extension = /volume1/@appstore/PHP5.6/usr/local/lib/php56/modules/ftp.so
> 3. that's it. No restarting of Web Station or the NAS is required, as php loads itself from the commandline each time a call is made to php.