# Fatal error: Call to undefined function ftp_ssl_connect() or ssh2_sftp()

Tags: php, ftp

I am trying to set up FTP using SSL connection in PHP. I try to use ftp_ssl_connect() and ssh2_sftp() but i got this error :

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function ftp_ssl_connect()
>
> Fatal error: Call to undefined function ssh2_connect()

I do have openssl extension turned on in PHP extentions.

> Array ( [0] => php [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35085677/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-ftp-ssl-connect) => file [2](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-sftp.php) => glob [3] => data [4] => http [5]
> => ftp [6] => zip [7] => compress.zlib [8] => compress.bzip2 [9] => https [10] => ftps [11] => phar )

Here's my simple code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35085677/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-ftp-ssl-connect) :

```
$conn_id = ftp_ssl_connect($ftp_server); 
$ftp_user_name = "username"; 
$ftp_user_pass = "password"; 
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass); 

ftp_pasv($conn_id, true); 
if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) { 
    echo "FTP connection has failed!"; 
    echo "Attempted to connect to $ftp_server for user $ftp_user_name"; 
    exit; 
} else { 
    echo "Connected to $ftp_server, for user $ftp_user_name"; 
}
```

And for SSH2 from [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-sftp.php) :

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('shell.example.com', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');

$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);
```

I'm using XAMPP, PHP 5.6.31 in Windows 10 and Mac OS X. Both OS, got the same error. Could anyone here wants to help me how to fix this ?

Comment: check for help:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/35085761/4248328 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/34936104/4248328

Comment: lets see what the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-ssl-connect.php) says **Note: Why this function may not exist

    ftp_ssl_connect() is only available if both the ftp module and the OpenSSL support is built statically into php, this means that on Windows this function will be undefined in the official PHP builds. To make this function available on Windows you must compile your own PHP binaries.**

Comment: Thx for your help, finally i found the FTP library from here https://github.com/Nicolab/php-ftp-client and my code is runing well.